# UITableViewController scrolling lag with large amount of images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have following code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"champion cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfChampionPictures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:cellIcon];

    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 70.0f, 70.0f);

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
    [cell.imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayOfChampionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Where `arrayOfChampionNames` is local database stored in `NSMutableArray` that contains pictures names. It's about 103 cells with images in my UITableView. It lags at first scroll from beginning to end, after that it's scrolling smoothly. There's no lags on simulator.

---

Possible solutions I came up with, but i don't know how to realise them

- Load images after scrolling,
- Preload image data into UITableView.

Comment: You need to reuse your cells and resize your images to the size of the cell's imageview - this is likely to be the cause for the lag you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot something:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"champion cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

This way you'll actually utilize the reusable identifier that you created.

Comment: and i forgot to mention that there's no lags on simulator

Comment: @anonymous Makes sense, never trust the simulator with this kind of thing. Your computer has a lot more RAM then you phone. And how large are the images you're using for the table?

Comment: 308 × 560 but UIImageView in cell displaying something like 88x88

Comment: try put operation with layers and resizing of image to if (cell == nil) condition

Answer (score 2):

I'll tell you where the lag is coming from - corner radius. Pre compute the images rounded corners. Doing them dynamically kills scrolling performance.